# Including only Eigen small matrices?

Tags: c++, compilation, eigen, compile-time

I do a lot of computational geometry, and so I often use eigen for the bigger/fancier linear algebra operations. This means that I don;t use things like glm, because it would make me spend a lot of time converting back and fort between eigen and whatever other linalg library.

However, the eigen dense header is bloated and uses about 40% of my compile time atm, more than any other file.

I know that 80% of the time the only eigen types I am using are vec2-4's and mat2-4's.

To speed up compilation time I want to include only those types and nothing else. Is it possible?

To speed up compilation I want to

Comment: Which type of matrix are you using? Those with sizes known at compile time, or those with dynamic sizes? I would expect compilation to be faster in the first case. Also pay attention to only include the used header files.

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers? It probably won't help save on code generation, but it might speed up parsing.

Comment: `Eigen::Vector2d` etc is just a typedef for `Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1>`. But if you only use basic operations, you should just include `Eigen/Core` and not `Eigen/Dense` (this may not safe a whole lot). Also, the general advice is to split your project into smaller compilation units where it is feasible.

Comment: I am only using types with size known at compile time.

Comment: Most of my files will use at least one of the Eigen types, so although my project is highly modularized into small hpp and CPP pairs, it does little to affect the time parsing the Eigen header.

Comment: I am not currently using precompiled headers.